# Problema con socket en express

Tags: nodejs, express, socket.io, router

Tengo un problema con el socket en mi programa. exporte la conexion de "io" y a pesar de que puedo emitir desde cualquier parte del programa normal (solo con hacer referencia a "io"), no puedo usar "socket" y emitir con el al menos que sea dentro de la misma conexion de "io". quisiera saber como usar socket desde cualquier otra parte del programa, con funciones como "socket.emit()" o "socket.broadcast.emit" etc. O como llamar a esta.

este es mi index.js:

```js
const express = require('express');
const restApi = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const server = require('http').createServer(restApi);
const rutas = require('./src/routes/Routes.js');
const io = require('./src/socket/SocketManager.js');
io.attach(server);

restApi.use(express.json());
restApi.use(express.static('public'));
restApi.use(cors());
restApi.options('*', cors());

server.listen(4040, () => console.log('Listening server in port 4040'));

restApi.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  next();
});

restApi.use('/api',rutas);
```

mi managersocket.js:

```js
const io = require('socket.io')();

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('NUEVA CONEXION: ',socket.id);
    socket.emit('recoger',socket.id);
});

module.exports = io;
```

en este proximo es en donde quisiera usar el socket o al menos llamar a la funcion.

y User.js:

```js
var io = require('../../socket/SocketManager');

var RouterUser = function(){

  this.practicafuncion = function (req,res){
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
    console.log('probando entrar por rest y que salga un mensaje por socket');
    res.send({
      status:'Aprobado',
      msj:'Enviado por rest'
    });
//este funciona correctamente.     io.sockets.emit('mensaje','**MENSAJESERVIDORPORSOCKET**');
//este no por el problema al usar "socket".   socket.broadcast.emit('mensaje','**MENSAJESERVIDORPORSOCKET**');
  };
}

module.exports = function(){
  var instancia = new RouterUser();
  return instancia;
};
```

igual aca esta el repositorio donde esta todo el codigo

```
https://github.com/proxirv/Socket.io-router
```